# Angular TypeScript Protractror end-2-end testing - remove need for browser.sleep() calls in code

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor, automated-tests

I am writing in interface in Angular with TypeScript. We use Protractor for end-2-end testing. Problem we have is that our screens have quite a few sections that fold/unfold, or modals that appear and close when buttons are clicked.

On these we have to add a `browser.sleep(500)` after the click to open them so that they will be open before the next part of the test runs.

**Is this the best way?** or should we be adding a call-back of sorts when the window/section is open/closed and only continuing when it is called?

```
if('the confirmation modal opens, I can accept', () => {
  element(by.id('openPopUpButton')).click();
  browser.sleep(500);
  expect(element(by.id('confirmationTextString')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I'm hesitant to add code that is specifically and solely to enable tests to run correctly.
I would prefer if we could rely on async/await or promises in some way, but is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browser.wait()` is a more nuanced version of sleep. Using [Expected Conditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) you can make your code wait until the desired condition. For example (Using your code)

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
element(by.id('openPopUpButton')).click();
let confirm = element(by.id('confirmationTextString'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(confirm),15000); //Timeout of 15 seconds
expect(confirm.getText()).toBe('Random Text') //Checked for text since wait basically checks for isPresent
```

If the element takes 1 second to become present, it will only wait 1 second, but if you are on a slow browser and it takes 10 seconds to load, your code will wait 10 seconds.